# Problem in using gsub function to remove $ sign from values

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am trying to remove "$" sign from a column, however, after using `gsup` I get `NAs introduced by coercion` , and it looks like that my code introduces NA. Please see example below:

```
structure(list(Strata.Maint.Fee = c("$672.00", "$670.00", "$670.00", 
"$67.88", "$67.88", "$67.88", "$67.88", "$67.88", "$67.86", "$67.86", 
"$1,056.2", "$1,056.2")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Then I use this code:

```
data_Selected$new = as.numeric(gsub("\\$", "", data_Selected$Strata.Maint.Fee))
```

The result would be:

```
   Strata.Maint.Fee   new
   <chr>            <dbl>
 1 $672.00          672  
 2 $670.00          670  
 3 $670.00          670  
 4 $67.88            67.9
 5 $67.88            67.9
 6 $67.88            67.9
 7 $67.88            67.9
 8 $67.88            67.9
 9 $67.86            67.9
10 $67.86            67.9
11 $1,056.2          NA
```

I am guessing that `,` in the last number makes a problem, but don't understand why. Can you please suggest how I should fix this?

Comment: On the shared `dput` data the code works correctly. In the shared data you have `$1056.2` and not `$1,056.2` as you have shown in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `parse_number`.  Based on the input showed, the last value also have a `,` which is not included in the `numeric` part.  So, either we use `parse_number`

```
library(dplyr)
data_Selected %>%
    mutate(new = readr::parse_number( Strata.Maint.Fee))
```

---

Or change the `gsub` to remove both `$` and `,`

```
as.numeric(gsub("[,$]", "", data_Selected$Strata.Maint.Fee))
```